# Azure: Publishing Deployment Update to Cloud Service Removes instances

Tags: azure, visual-studio

I'm doing some testing on Azure cloud services with one of the sample apps they provide.  I've deployed it as a cloud service with two instances but, whenever I update my app and republish the instance count goes from two to one.  It's like its deleting the cloud service and starting from scratch again.

In my publish settings I've selected Deployment Update and incremental update which I thought would fix this but to no avail.  Is there something I'm missing?

I'm publishing using Visual Studio Community 2013

Answer (score 0):

Check the file for your services configuration. It will probably be called something like ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg. It may have an instances count set to 1 and be reconfiguring your Cloud Service. Setting this to 2 will deploy with two instances.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this out.  In order to keep the number of instances intact you need to deselect the 'Enable Web Deploy for all web roles' option in Common Settings.